# How to use parallel executions of circuits?

Tags: qiskit

I am trying to run multiple circuits in parallel using the documentation [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/api/qiskit.providers.aer.QasmSimulator.html?highlight=qasm%20simulator). My codes are:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.quantumregister import QuantumRegister
from qiskit.circuit.classicalregister import ClassicalRegister
from qiskit import Aer, execute
from qiskit.providers.aer.backends import QasmSimulator

def apply_measurement(circ):
    c = ClassicalRegister(len(circ.qubits), 'c')
    meas = QuantumCircuit(circ.qregs[0], c)
    meas.barrier(circ.qubits)
    meas.measure(circ.qubits,c)
    qc = circ+meas
    return qc

qr = QuantumRegister(4)
circ = QuantumCircuit(qr)
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(i+1,4):
        circ.cx(i,j)

qc = apply_measurement(circ)
circuits = [qc for i in range(3)]
num_shots = int(1e6)

backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
backend_options = {'method': 'automatic','max_parallel_threads':1,'max_parallel_experiments':1,'max_parallel_shots':1}
noiseless_qasm_result = execute(circuits, backend, shots=num_shots, backend_options=backend_options).result()
print(noiseless_qasm_result)

backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
backend_options = {'method': 'automatic','max_parallel_threads':1,'max_parallel_experiments':3,'max_parallel_shots':1}
noiseless_qasm_result = execute(circuits, backend, shots=num_shots, backend_options=backend_options).result()
print(noiseless_qasm_result)
```

Where I am running three copies of the same circuit. I did not see any changes in the `result` object obtained, nor is there any runtime improvement. Both take about 10 seconds. What should be the proper way to run those three circuits in parallel?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your `max_parallel_threads` value to more than 1.

Quoting from the [documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/api/qiskit.providers.aer.QasmSimulator.html?highlight=qasm%20simulator):

> `max_parallel_threads` (int): Sets the maximum number of CPU cores
>   used by OpenMP for parallelization. If set to 0 the maximum will be
>   set to the number of CPU cores (Default: 0).
>
> `max_parallel_experiments` (int): Sets the maximum number of qobj
>   experiments that may be executed in parallel up to the
>   max_parallel_threads value. If set to 1 parallel circuit execution
>   will be disabled. If set to 0 the maximum will be automatically set to
>   max_parallel_threads (Default: 1).

Comment: That does change the ```parallel_state_update```, but there still is no runtime improvement. It still takes about 10 seconds to run.

Comment: Could you also change the `max_parallalel_shots` and check

Comment: Another option I would try is to change everything to defaults and check the behavior according to the documentation.

Comment: It seems like ```max_parallel_experiments``` is the only parameter that does something. I get the best runtime when set ```max_parallel_threads``` to be the default 0 and ```max_parallel_shots``` to be the default 1. Setting ```max_parallel_experiments``` to be 0 does nothing, you have to explicitly set it to number of CPUs. The documentation is wrong for the default cases.